Намеренное переполнение буфера и переход в другую функцию за счёт этого переполнения
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void input(char *a)
{
    char overflow[4]; // Будем переполнять здесь
    gets(overflow); // Небезопасное чтение: не котролирует размер вводимых данных
}

void other() // Переход после переполнения в эту функцию
{
    fprintf(stderr, "other\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    fprintf(stdout,"Введите Вашу строку:\n");
    input(argv[1]); // Передаём аргумент в функцию небезопасного чтения
    fprintf(stdout, "main\n");

    return 0;
}

Есть вот такой код. Необходимо подобрать готовый ввод чтобы после переполнения буфера попасть в функцию other(как раз за счёт переполнения) чтобы она написала строку а потом программа завершилась любым способом. Это необходимо провести с включенным ASLR. Смещение между адресами функций при каждом запуске остается постоянным, но сами адреса изменяются. Скорее всего 4 символа буфера можно заполнить любыми значениями, но как подобрать продолжение, которое как раз приведёт к переходу в other? Взял в таблице ASCII символ равный смещению буфер заполнил 4 буквами A а регистр(где-то видел, что так нужно) 8 буквами A под смещение подходила символ G, но почему-то функция other не отработала. Подскажите, что подправить?
0000000000001189 <input>:
    1189:  f3 0f 1e fa            endbr64
    118d:  55                     push   %rbp
    118e:  48 89 e5               mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1191:  48 83 ec 20            sub    $0x20,%rsp
    1195:  48 89 7d e8            mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
    1199:  64 48 8b 04 25 28 00   mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
    11a0:  00 00 
    11a2:  48 89 45 f8            mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
    11a6:  31 c0                  xor    %eax,%eax
    11a8:  48 8d 45 f4            lea    -0xc(%rbp),%rax
    11ac:  48 89 c7               mov    %rax,%rdi
    11af:  b8 00 00 00 00         mov    $0x0,%eax
    11b4:  e8 c7 fe ff ff         call   1080 <gets@plt>
    11b9:  90                     nop
    11ba:  48 8b 45 f8            mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
    11be:  64 48 2b 04 25 28 00   sub    %fs:0x28,%rax
    11c5:  00 00 
    11c7:  74 05                  je     11ce <input+0x45>
    11c9:  e8 a2 fe ff ff         call   1070 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
    11ce:  c9                     leave
    11cf:  c3                     ret

00000000000011d0 <other>:
    11d0:  f3 0f 1e fa            endbr64
    11d4:  55                     push   %rbp
    11d5:  48 89 e5               mov    %rsp,%rbp
    11d8:  48 8b 05 61 2e 00 00   mov    0x2e61(%rip),%rax        # 4040 <stderr@GLIBC_2.2.5>
    11df:  48 89 c1               mov    %rax,%rcx
    11e2:  ba 06 00 00 00         mov    $0x6,%edx
    11e7:  be 01 00 00 00         mov    $0x1,%esi
    11ec:  48 8d 05 11 0e 00 00   lea    0xe11(%rip),%rax        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
    11f3:  48 89 c7               mov    %rax,%rdi
    11f6:  e8 95 fe ff ff         call   1090 <fwrite@plt>
    11fb:  90                     nop
    11fc:  5d                     pop    %rbp
    11fd:  c3                     ret

Вот информация из objdump


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Зависит не только от компилятора, но и от конкретных ключей компиляции...

нужно ещё убедить компилятор поставить функцию other после функции input а дальше нужно NOP символов навалить что бы возврат из функции не сработал. Потому что как будто безусловный переход тут не сильно поможет.

Чтобы ответить, нужно дизассемблировать исполнимый модуль.

Дизассемблируете исполняемый модуль (например, используя objdump) и ищете в нем код, соответствующий функции input, а также определяете адрес функции output. Путем анализа кода input определяете смещение в стеке адреса возврата из input от начала массива overflow[]. Подготавливаете такую строку, чтобы записанный в нее (естественно, в binary) адрес output попал по адресу возврата из input. Отключаете ASLR и запускаете свою программу, подсовывая ей подготовленную для атаки строку. В принципе, все. (при отладке в gdb ASLR отключать не надо)

Тут есть, конечно, такой неприятный подводный камень ... - нужный вам адрес не должен содержать где-то байт, численно равный '\n' (нули можно) (последний байт равный \n тоже можно)

Для начала попробуйте в отладчике gdb. Остановитесь на выходе из gets и посмотрите, какой именно адрес оказался на месте адреса возврата из input. Далее пройдитесь в отладчике по шагам (по машинным командам) и смотрите что происходит. Возможно отрабатывает call   1070 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>. Тогда надо думать,  какие именно символы кроме адреса возврата должны переполнять буфер, чтобы эта проверка прошла. (Но что делать, чтобы это все работало при включенном ASLR я не знаю. Буду благодарен, что вы расскажите нам об этом, когда все же решите эту задачу)
